# What CMS: Sitecore, KEntico, EPIServer or multiple?

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system

At this point we are developing Sitecore websites and we are gaining experience every day. This means that we know how to adjust our approach to different types of customers and that we are able to build our applications quicker every project we do. Offcourse Sitecore is not the only W-CMS around and we have looked into other W-CMS's. What are the pro's and the con's for a company to offer solutions in different types of CMS's and what would this mean for the programmers that are working with this CMS? Would a choice to offer solutions in more CMS's automatically mean that the global experience per CMS will shrink relative? Hope there are some people around with experience in multiple big W-CMS's (Sitecore, KEntico, EPIServer, etc.. etc..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice to go for one or more CMS-es depends strongly on the structure of the company in which this has to be introduced. If the company for example has a lot of .NET developers and they are all capable of working with different cms-es you can offer your customers more then one cms implementation. For now I will state this as an answer of my own question, because we had some internal discussions about this and I don't want to wait any longer for an answer since it seems it won't happen to come anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice Kentico. Cheaper than EPIServer and (IMO) better. The community surrounding it is awesome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) - great for .NET developers, and easy to extend/customise.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I think a lot depends on the size of your agency, history and staff skills. After a lot of consideration and evaluation of many W-CMS systems we decided to go down the Kentico route here at Pull Digital.
It’s probably one of the best decisions we made, we also work with other CMS platforms and aspdotnetstorefront for e-commerce projects. Obviously we are more Microsoft focused, this is due to the inherited infrastructure and staff skill set we have.
The support from Kentico has been great and we have a great relationship with all the key people.

We recently got our staff certified, I have to admit that you can’t pass their exams unless you actively use Kentico and have done a number of projects. It’s a good way to make sure implementations of Kentico are done by qualified staff / partners.
In my experience Kentico have been very fair and are really working hard to enhance the product.